# Control Spotify from your own app

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, spotify, swift3

I want to put in my app just one PLAY button and when user will press on that button, to play the song directly in Spotify. It will like a controller, so I can switch songs in Spotify from my own app.

Now I created something, but it plays on my own app. Is there any ways to control my music streaming in spotify via my own app?

For example I press "Next song" and it switches in Spotify app to the next song.

I hope I could explain what I want, if not - please ask me

Answer (score 1):

URL Schemes are the only way to communicate between apps. It is not possible to launch non arbitrary apps.

Then you need to use [Spotifys API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/) and they do not currently have any support for that.

Comment: so can't I control the Spotify player from my app? =/

Comment: Unfortunately not. Think of it in this way, what if someone else could control your app and do whatever they want with it. @Doe

Comment: I´m not 100% sure of how that works, but I think that Apple will reject the app because of the issue I wrote in my answer. Not 100% though, just what I think after been reading Apples policy for App Store.